# Setting up an error message for minimum quantity in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I set up a minimum quantity for a product category in WooCommerce. In my case I set the minimum quantity to 5 items. The code I use works fine but I would like to add two error messages for the customer:

1) If the customer tries to change the the quantity to less than the minimum by clicking the "-" symbol I would like to have something like: "The minimum quantity of this product is 5, please add at least 5 items to the basket"

2) If the customer clicks the "add to the basket" button I would like to have something like this: "There is a minimum quantity of 5 items for this product. Please check your basket"

Is there some code I can add to my actual code?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'min_qty_filter_callback', 20, 2 );

function min_qty_filter_callback( $args, $product ) {
    $category = 'Noten'; // The targeted product category
    $min_qty  = 5; // The minimum product quantity

    $product_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){
        $args['min_value'] = $min_qty;
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For add to cart validation add the follows code snippet to validate your item quantity -

```
    function add_to_cart_validation( $flag, $product_id, $qunatity ) { 
    if( $qunatity < 5 ) { // if quantity less than 5
        wc_add_notice( __( 'There is a minimum quantity of 5 items for this product. Please check your basket', 'text-domain' ), 'error' );
        $flag = false;
    }
    return $flag;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'add_to_cart_validation', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code doesn't work even I corrected it to "quantity". I tried also quantity = 5 but also doesn't work. Any ideas?